# Do we really need to ensure giving up ownership when moving a `unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I'm reading Nicolai M. Josuttis's [C++ Move Semantics - The Complete Guide](https://www.cppmove.com/) book (which is pretty good imho) and I'm not sure I agree with  the comments in one of the examples.

Quote (from 6.1.2 - Guaranteed States of Moved-From Objects):

> Similar code can be useful to release memory for an object that a unique pointer uses:

```
draw(std::move(up));  // the unique pointer might or might not give up ownership
up.reset();           // ensure we give up ownership and release any resource
```

Let's assume that the `up` variable is indeed `unique_ptr` and the `draw` function receives the `unique_ptr` by value (otherwise, what's the point of moving the pointer to a "passed-by-ref" function).

I understand that it is legal to call `reset` on a "moved-from" object.
But what I do not understand is why it is "required" in order to "ensure we give up ownership and release any resource" and how is it possible that "the unique pointer **might or might not** give up ownership"?

After all, `unique_ptr`s cannot be copied and the whole idea is that they guarantee only one ownership.

So, afaik, if my two assumptions are correct, there is no need to call the `reset` function to ensure the ownership was given away.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, we don't need to care of that.

Comment: If `draw` takes an rvalue reference, you don't know for sure if it accepts ownership, or just takes a look and ignores the pointer.

Comment: @BoP Nice idea. Any reason for `draw` to take rvalue reference only to "take a look"?

Comment: For a function called `draw`, not really. But in general a function might throw an exception before it has completed its work. Then, who knows?

Comment: If `draw` takes rvalue reference only to take a look, it's not following GotW#91.  But that's just GotW#91 as *best practices*.  Maybe the coding convention being used in some code was (in my opinion) **not** best practices... but is still perfectly legal code (awkwardness aside).

Comment: `draw` might take ownership conditionally. (E.g., "If there is nothing to draw, then ignore the parameter since we have no use for it.") The `reset` forces the resource to be released if `draw` chose not to consume it.

Comment: Move construction and move assignment already transfer the ownership. That reset is redundant

Comment: It will at least conceptually move ownership. After the move the orignal object must be left in an unspecified but valid state (so it can be destructed). Note `std::move` doesn't really do anything directly. So it is indeed to the internals of draw what do with it (though I must admit I find the fact that the code needs documenting quite surprising, it would be more consistent for draw to always take ownership. So bad example)

Comment: @Vivick No, the actual move should happen inside the implementation of draw and that implementation is not shown here. Imagine draw has NO implementation, then no move is performed (std::move itself doesn't move). But yeah IMO  such an implementation violates the "no surprises" guideline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if the parameter is accepted by value, then we have the guarantee that it's actually being moved from, not just maybe, and that ownership over resources is given up (unless the move constructor does nothing, but that would be nonsensical). We might have to call `.reset()` otherwise for two possible reasons:

#### You may have to `.reset()` if the argument isn't *always* moved from

Consider the following signature:

```cpp
void draw(std::unique_ptr<T> &&uptr);
```

Such a signature is generally preferred over accepting moved-from parameters by value by [CppCoreGuidelines F.18: For “will-move-from” parameters, pass by X&& and std::move the parameter](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-consume), although an exception is made for types like `std::unique_ptr`.

In such a case, we don't know whether `draw` moves from the `uptr` for sure unless we look at its implementation:

```cpp
void draw(std::unique_ptr<T> &&uptr) {
    // If 'condition' is false, then 'uptr' won't be moved from, and the
    // caller may have to .reset() to free up resources immediately.
    if (condition) {
        process_further(std::move(uptr));
    }
}
```

#### You may have to `.reset()` for swapping move assignment

Furthermore, a few people tend to implement the move assignment operator as follows:

```cpp
T& operator=(T&& other) noexcept {
    this->swap(other);
    return *this;
}

void draw(std::unique_ptr<T> &&uptr) {
    // This effectively swaps 'something' with 'uptr', which means that
    // the caller has to .reset() to free the resources in 'something',
    // unless they can rely on the destructor of 'uptr' to do that.
    something = std::move(uptr);
}
```

This forces the caller to use `.reset()` if they want these resources freed immediately, not when the argument goes out of scope.

No standard library types implement move assignment like this, and it's overall not a good idea, but it is valid, and may force us to make the call.